# why undefined is not getting removed

Tags: php

I see this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: pageno in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ims\public\includes\process.php on line 81 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '-5,5' at line
>   1

```
    //manage category
if(isset($_POST["manageCategory"])){

    $m = new Manage();
    $result = $m->manageRecordWithPagination("categories",$_POST["pageno"]);
    $rows = $result["rows"];
    $pagination = $result["pagination"];

    if(count($rows)> 0){
        $n = 0;
        foreach ($rows as $row){
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo ++$n; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["category"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["parent"]; ?></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Active</a></td>
        <td>
         <a href ="#" did="" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</a>
         <a href ="#" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">Edit</a>
        </td>
      </tr>

    <?php

        }
        ?>

        <tr><td colspan="5"><?php echo $pagination; ?></td></tr>
        <?php
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: You are actually (hint!) seeing two errors, but you are not asking a question. Please, read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: It seems `$_POST["pageno"]` does not exist. About the other error in database query, show us the code.

Comment: change your 1st if condtion to `if(isset($_POST["manageCategory"]) && isset($_POST["pageno"])){}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: you should avoid using $_POST, $_GET etc without data validation

Answer (score 0):

There are high possibility that "pageno" is not defined in your $_POST , so to check this you need to run this statement :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Kindly check its existence.

Comment: yes it is not defined..but how can i solve this problem